# log4j asyncappender thread dies with main thread

Tags: java, asynchronous, jdbc, log4j

I have created a test app to log events using log4j jdbcAppender and asyncAppender. in a while loop I log 500 error messages using the asyncAppender, the problem is that when the thread that logs the message are done the asyncAppender thread also stops logging the messages to the database.

```
<appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
        <param name="bufferSize" value="1"/> 
        <param name="blocking" value="false"/>
        <appender-ref ref="test_db"/> 
    </appender>
```

The idea is to log the errors to the database without blocking. setting the blocking to true logs all the messages but makes the main thread wait for the logging. any ideas on a solution?

the bufferSize is set to 1 so that it logs the messages to the database each time it comes through, the reason is because there are an alerting system on the db to check the amount of errors etc. I have also changed the jdbcAppender to use a connection pool and not open connection with each log event.

thanks.

update:
jdbc appender

```
<appender name="test_db" class="com.test.pooled.log4j.jdbcappender.PooledJDBCAppender"> <!-- EXTENDS JDBCAPPENDER TO USE CONNECTION POOL INSTEAD! -->
        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
        <param name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/~removed~"/>
        <param name="Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <param name="User" value="~removed~"/>
        <param name="Password" value="~removed~"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                   value="INSERT INTO ~removed this detail~
             /> 
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: show your configuration for `JDBCAppender` ?

Comment: How are you testing it? If the `AsyncAppender` is running in a daemon thread, it will die when all non-daemon threads have finished.

Comment: jdbc appender added. testing it using a basic test app to log a few error messages.

Comment: @Kayaman so if i have an app which creates thread A and thread B, and A logs 500 error messages to the async appender and then stops but thread B is still running, will the async appender stop with Thread A or will continue to log because Thread B is still running?

Comment: If thread B is non-daemon and the async logger thread is daemon, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shutdown hook as [doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHook) said will be fine:

```
<configuration debug="true">
   <!-- in the absence of the class attribute, assume 
   ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DefaultShutdownHook -->
   <shutdownHook/>
  .... 
</configuration>
```